# How to send web push notification when column value in database is changed for particular user?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, push-notification

For the past 2 days I've been researching about web push notifications as it is a new topic and something that I am getting in touch for the first time in development.

I've found many done web push notification services as [Wonderpush](https://www.wonderpush.com/) and [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/webpush). So far regarding to these services, I've been mostly intrigued by OneSignal and what they've done and how they've done neat user-interface from enabling push notification to push notifications itself.

The thing is, I can't figure out if these will go along with my requirements, as I need to trigger action (show push notification) when column in database is updated, but the thing is, it's not same for everyone. The situation is following, I have database of customer's cars and of course one customer can have multiple cars and car can have only one owner and there's column "carStatus" which can have value `Done`, `In Process` and `On Hold`. So, I'd have to modify Web Push Notification to do following: Let's say default value of carStatus is `On Hold`, when it changes to let's say `Done`, I'd want to send push notification to user which that particular car belongs to.

My first question, is something like that even achievable with OneSignal or I would have to write custom code for it?

My second question, if I'd have to write custom code for this, do you have any good resources on Web Push Notification except from MDN as I don't find it way too useful for mine case and it seems like general stuff.